# set of infinite sequences so every two sequences are equal is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove the following theorem:

> let $X$ be a set of infinite sequences of natural numbers so every two sequences are equal from some point. Then $X$ is countable.

I tried a bunch of different ways to prove them but I could not get to the conclusion. How do I prove it?

Comment: It seems that at some point they all become equal.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Fix one sequence $(a_n)$ from$X$. For any $(x_n) \in X$ define $f(x_n)=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_N\}$ where $N$ is the least integer such that $x_i=a_i$ for all $i >N$. Very that this is  an injective map from $X$ into the collection  of all finite subsets of $\mathbb N$.